# Inspect object in memory in Firefox to detect leak

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks

My Angular application is accumulating memory in Firefox, but not in Chrome. From the memory snapshot tool in Firefox, I can see that 'Objects' and 'Strings' are increasing in size and count over time.

The best way to debug this (in my mind) would be to look at some example 'objets' and 'strings' that are added to memory, to identify where the leak is coming from.

However, I've not been able to extract this information from Firefox or Firefox Developer Edition.

Hence my question: **Do you know of a way to inspect object in memory in Firefox?** Or of another way to identify the leak without having to guess?

Here is a screenshot of what I see (left: chrome, constant memory around ~35mb, right: firefox accumulating memory)

[image: screenshot of chrome and firefox memory]